# Redux + Selector unknown returned the root state when called. This can lead to unnecessary rerenders. ... warning + where state is an array

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, state, useselector

I am using Redux 5 in my React 18 application. When using the `useSelector()` method from the `react-redux` package, I get the below warning in the browser console:

```
Selector unknown returned the root state when called. This can lead to unnecessary rerenders.
Selectors that return the entire state are almost certainly a mistake, as they will cause a rerender whenever *anything* in state changes.
```

I have also seen the redux documentation for this warning at https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#identity-function-state--state-check, however, the problem I am facing is that "the state is an array" in my code. Please see my files below:

`Notes.jsx`

```js
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { toggleImportanceOf } from '../reducers/noteReducer';

const Note = ({ note, handleClick }) => {
  return (
    <li onClick={handleClick}>
      {note.content}
      <strong> {note.important ? 'important' : ''}</strong>
    </li>
  );
};

const Notes = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const notes = useSelector((state) => {
    console.log(state);  // THIS IS AN ARRAY
    return state;
  });

  return (
    <ul>
      {notes.map((note) => (
        <Note
          key={note.id}
          note={note}
          handleClick={() => dispatch(toggleImportanceOf(note.id))}
        />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

export default Notes;
```

`noteReducer.js` is my reducer

```
const noteReducer = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'NEW_NOTE':
      return [...state, action.payload];
    case 'TOGGLE_IMPORTANCE': {
      const id = action.payload.id;
      const noteToChange = state.find((n) => n.id === id);
      const changedNote = {
        ...noteToChange,
        important: !noteToChange.important,
      };
      return state.map((note) => (note.id !== id ? note : changedNote));
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const generateId = () => Number((Math.random() * 1000000).toFixed(0));

export const createNote = (content) => {
  return {
    type: 'NEW_NOTE',
    payload: {
      content,
      important: false,
      id: generateId(),
    },
  };
};

export const toggleImportanceOf = (id) => {
  return {
    type: 'TOGGLE_IMPORTANCE',
    payload: { id },
  };
};

export default noteReducer;
```

`main.jsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import App from './App';
import noteReducer from './reducers/noteReducer';

const store = createStore(noteReducer);

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
);
```

Please note, I know that `createStore` is deprecated. This is just an introductory lesson and we will be learning about the new method that has replaced the `createStore` method.

The array of the state is as below:

[image]

The array contents get filled in a form and the list is then rendered on the UI. Please see image below:

[image]

QUESTION: How can I fix this warning in my browser console for a 'state' that is an array?

[image]

Comment: Do you have plans to add more to your Redux state? Using redux to store a single array seems like incredible overkill. You can nest the array under a root property or anywhere deeper in the `state` object, or you may be able to use an [equality comparason](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#equality-comparisons-and-updates). If you need more help can you [edit] to include your Redux code, i.e. the reducer(s) and store as part of a more complete [mcve]?

Comment: I recently started learning redux and this is just an introduction example that I was following through. So, at the moment I believe it is only this much. I just added the reducer code as well above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you should just not ever have a selector function that returns the entire state object.

Nest the `notes` state under a `notes` property in the state and select that.

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore, combineReducers } from "redux";
import App from "./App";
import noteReducer from "./reducers/noteReducer";

// Create a root reducer function
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  notes: noteReducer // <-- note reducer forms state.notes
});
const store = createStore(rootReducer);

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </StrictMode>
);
```

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { toggleImportanceOf } from "./reducers/noteReducer";
import { useEffect } from "react";

const Note = ({ note, handleClick }) => {
  return (
    <li onClick={handleClick}>
      {note.content}
      <strong> {note.important ? "important" : ""}</strong>
    </li>
  );
};

const Notes = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const notes = useSelector((state) => state.notes); // <-- select state.notes array

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(notes);
  }, [notes]);

  return (
    <ul>
      {notes.map((note) => (
        <Note
          key={note.id}
          note={note}
          handleClick={() => dispatch(toggleImportanceOf(note.id))}
        />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

export default Notes;
```

Note also that you are also learning what is effectively "deprecated" Redux. Modern Redux is written using the [Redux-Toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/) library, which is more streamlined and much less boilerplatey.